# Hotmail issue with hyperlink in my verification emails

Tags: hotmail, email-verification

i just realized am sending a verification email to users/mebers but people how have hotmail account hey cant click the link...is basically stripped... what am doing wrong? there is a workaround?

thanks

Comment: UPDATE: i found the solution: it is my fault because I thought the Hotmail webmail would create the hyperlink anyway form a http:.. plain string, but it doesn't... so i had experince with some users using a desktop client that were able to see it and other dont... in the end i just creted a full html email with a regular <a> link.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that it's stripped, do you mean the hyperlink is stripped, or the link itself is stripped? If the former, try sending just a plaintext link for them to copy and paste into the address bar. If the link itself is being removed from the email, you might try formatting the link in such a way that it doesn't appear to be a link, or create a manual verification for Hotmail users.